# Strip list to compare with another list

Tags: python

I try to import a list in python. 
However, I would like to customize my code in such a way, that the list will look like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

instead of like this:

```
[["['a','b','c']"]]
```

The reason is that I have to compare if a list is in another list and it won't succeed when the list is not formatted well.
The rest of the code looks like this:

```
def check(a1, a2):
    listA = []
    listB = []
    listA.append(a1)
    listB.append(a2)
    if listA in listB:
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "formatted well" and how do strings and printing come into play here?

Comment: Well, I would like that when I append a1 to listA, the list will be stripped (or something in a way like that) so that when I print listA, it looks like how I mentioned it above. So that I can compare the list with another list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Are you looking for this?

```
a = ['some', 'list', 'items']
print ', '.join(a)
```

This will print

```
some, list, items
```

But that probably won't solve what you're trying to do. Comparing two lists shouldn't involve print at all.

Comment: you're right, it's bad to convert list as string just to be able to use `in` in the string. So it kind of answers.

Comment: No I was not very clear in my question. I changed the question now. I want my list like this: ['a', 'b', 'c'] instead of like [["['a','b','c']"]]. Now, it looks like the last example, because I got that data from an .txt file. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure. So you have a string like `"['a', 'b', 'c']"` and you would like to turn that into the python list ['a', 'b', 'c'] ? Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is right!

Comment: Then use my answer and just take away the joining part

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
weirdlist=[["['a','b','c']"]]
print(", ".join(ast.literal_eval(weirdlist[0][0])))
```

Try this. Formats it like this: `a, b, c`

EDIT: It seems like the question-asker wanted a list, not a string:

```
import ast
weirdlist=[["['a','b','c']"]]
print(ast.literal_eval(weirdlist[0][0]))
```

Comment: Just use `ast.literal_eval`...

Comment: I made the edit